# HTML image tag leading to the error 'Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor'

Tags: html, responsive-images

I'm trying to build a simple HTML page to implement responsive images for practice.

This is my whole code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Practice</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Sample Header</h1>

<img srcset = "D:\Web Projects\praxis\img\60.jpg 1723w,
             D:\Web Projects\pl\praxis\13.jpg 2400w"
     sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 1723px,<!--I assume that this tells the browser to load the smaller image if browser's width is less than 1000px-->
            2400px"
     src="D:\Web Projects\praxis\img\13.jpg"
     alt="Sample alternative">
     
</body>
</HTML>
```

When I open this web-page, it just shows the larger image (D:\Web Projects\praxis\img\13.jpg) even after resizing the browser window to a small width. In the console, I get two error messages:

1. Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor.
2. Dropped srcset candidate "D:\Web"

Searching online through other solutions indicate that it is usually a faulty image source URL incorrect srcset formatting. I can't figure out where my code is going wrong.

Comment: Certainly `D:\` is not recognized as a valid scheme here, try `file://` instead or even better, run a local server.

Comment: @Kaiido But it _does_ show the image even when 'D:' is used

Comment: @CharlieKeith Copy the URL from the URL bar when viewing the image with `D:\...` and you'll know.

Comment: @N3R4ZZuRR0 I altered the URLs to look like this 'file:///D:/Web%20Projects/pl/img/13.jpg', but now only the smaller image loads and doesn't change when the Window is resized.